# How can I create a new Firebase Admin SDK server in NodeJS to authenticate with LinkedIn?

Tags: node.js, firebase, linkedin-api, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I've never worked with NodeJS, and I need to create a Firebase custom token so I can authenticate to my iOS app via LinkedIn.

According to the Firebase documentation, I have to create a new [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) server. I'm following the NodeJS instructions, but they're not well explained. I don't understand how to communicate to the server with my app, and I can't find much documentation about it.

Has someone done this before? If so, I will appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out the [`firebase/custom-auth-samples`](https://github.com/firebase/custom-auth-samples) GitHub repo which has some examples of how to do Line and Instagram custom authentication using the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK. You can use the code there to do a similar thing for LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following simplified flow(other ways to do it too):

- (assuming you have the infrastructure to do that) Sign in with linkedIn in your iOS app. Once that's done, send the linkedIn OAuth access token to your backend running node.js.
- On your backend, query the linkedIn userinfo endpoint with that access token. Get the linkedIn userId, displayName, photoUrl.
- Using the linkedIn userID, mint a customToken using the node.js admin SDK and set the uid to the linkedIn userID. You can prefix it with something to prevent collision.
- Return the custom token, displayName and photoUrl to your iOS app.
- Call signInWithCustom using that custom token returned to sign in that user.
- Set the displayName and photoURL on that logged in user.

You now have a linkedIn user with their linkedIn display name and photoURL logged in to firebase.